# How do I use POST with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How do i use ajax to send POST requests to the server instead of GET?

Comment: Are you using any particular javascript library?  It varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you really should sit down and read about Ajax if you can not figure out how to move from a GET to a POST. That is Ajax 101 stuff:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/AJAX

Answer (score 3):

Since I think that you're using the XHR object directly, you can make an 'postRequest' function easily:

We need the request **`url`**, the parameters to be send (**`params`**), and at least two callback functions **`success`**, which receives the responseText as the first argument when the request is completed successfully, and the **`error`** callback, which receives the XHR object and the status text:

```
function postRequest (url, params, success, error) {  
  var xhr = window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") : 
                                   new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  xhr.open("POST", url, true); 
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ 
    if ( xhr.readyState == 4 ) { 
      if ( xhr.status == 200 ) { 
        success(xhr.responseText); 
      } else { 
        error(xhr, xhr.status); 
      } 
    } 
  }; 
  xhr.send(params); 
}
```

Comment: @CMS: Your var xhr line is flawed on IE8/IE7 that have native support and ActiveX disabled. The ActiveX will throw an error and it will totally ignore the native support. Not good since it still could make a call. That is why it is important to use try catch which most libraries ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Put POST in as the first argument to xmlhttp.open() assuming you're using pure javascript:

```
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'example.php', true);
```

Comment: don't i have to add some other stuff? and where do parameters go?

Comment: More detail (at least a link to it) would sincerely help. Also, any indication of cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using jquery:

```
$.post("pageToPost.php", { firstParam: "Foo", secondParam: "Foo2" }, function(result){
alert("Response from pageToPost: " + result);
});
```

Comment: it would be ideal if i didn't use jquery.

Comment: Consider it as a valid option Jcubed. IMHO Jquery, as other javascript frameworks are great wrappers for great functionality and solving cross-browsing issues.

Answer (score 0):

[YUI connection manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/connection/) would also be worth taking a look at as an alternative to jQuery. Using that you can make an ajax POST request as follows:

```
YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', 'php/post.php', callback, "new=1&old=2");
```